# Encrypt files in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

My script generates two files (a database dump and a zip file), both can be very large (1 GB+). Now I want to encrypt these file with a password (as I want to keep it symmetric and easy decodable). I was looking for encoding the zip file in PHP at creation time, but it does not look like that `ZIPArchive` supports that. So I have to encode it after creation.

What possibilities are there for encoding files with PHP? I prefer mcrypt at the moment, but are there any other possibilities? Have anyone experience with the performance with large files? It should be a solution which is ready to run on the most systems - of course mcrypt need to be installed, but this should not be a problem, because it is nearly a standard configuration these days.

Comment: Although it has not yet been accepted, I did propose a [large file encryption feature](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/pull/78) to [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) for version 2.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can just include the password in the archived files and rename file without extension for using small resource. 
Reference: [ZipArchive::setPassword](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php).

Comment: This is only possible from PHP 5.6. Also, it is only supported for decryption.

Comment: please let me know your server specification like php version, installed plugins, or other? alternative, you can try aes encryption [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8369-PHP-Encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-a-given-key-and-salt.html#view_files/files).

Comment: The application should also run on customers servers, my system requirement is PHP 5.5.